# Prove that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (\frac{\ln x}{x})^n$ converge uniformly

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

How to prove that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (\frac{\ln x}{x})^n$ is uniformly convergent for $ x \in [1,+\infty)$, I tried the Weierstrass M-test but it doesn't work. Is there another way to prove this?

Comment: Why you don't try the root test?

Answer (score 4):

Observe
\begin{align}
\log x \leq
\begin{cases}
x-1 & \text{ if } 1 \leq x \leq 2\\
\frac{1}{2}x & \text{ if } x> 2
\end{cases}
\end{align}
which means
\begin{align}
\frac{\log x}{x} \leq \frac{1}{2}
\end{align}
for all $x\geq 1$. Then it follows
\begin{align}
\sum^\infty_{n=1}\left(\frac{\log x}{x}\right)^n \leq \sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac{1}{2^n}.
\end{align}

Answer (score 3):

If you consider $$f(x)=\frac{\log(x)} x\implies f'(x)=\frac{1-\log (x)}{x^2}\implies f''(x)= \frac{2 \log (x)-3}{x^3}$$ So,$f'(x)=0$ if $x=e$ and this a maximum (by the second derivative test). So, for $x \in [1,+\infty)$, $f(x)\leq \frac 1 e$.

Then,  for any $x \in [1,+\infty)$, 
$$\begin{align}
\sum^\infty_{n=1}\left(\frac{\log x}{x}\right)^n \lt \sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac{1}{e^n}=\frac{1}{e-1}
\end{align}$$